# css not loaded using CDN

Tags: magento-1.9, cdn, cloudfront-cdn

The Problem is not loaded stylesheet because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".

We are using cdn on aws.

I added to below line on apache server.

AddType text/css .css 
AddType text/javascript .js

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is coming directly from your server, just [invalidate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) the file from the cloudfront cache file as well to pick up the new MIME time or just rename the css file, [named versioning is recommended for css/js assets while using cloudfront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ReplacingObjects.html)